# Duplicating text within prompt - Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am working on a Node.js program that takes input and adds it to a list. I am going to use this program through terminal. I have written the following function.

Problem Areas:

```
add: function () {
            console.log("What do you want to add to the ToDo List?");
            // Starts the prompt
            prompt.start();
            // Gets input called content
            prompt.get(['content'], function(err, result) {
                content = result.content
                // Pushed content to the list
                toDo.list.push(content);
            });
```

It is called when this switch command exicutes.

```
switch (command){
                    case "list":
                        toDo.print();
                        break;
                    case "add":
                        toDo.add();
                        break;
                }
```

The issue is that all the input next duplicates while I input it.

Output:

[image]

All my Code (if you need it):

```
var prompt = require('prompt');

// Empty variables that we will use for prompt input
var content = "";
var command = "";
// Exits the program when this variable changes state
var done = false;

// Object that holds all functions and data for the ToDo portion of this program
var toDo = {
    // List that everything all ToDos will be stored within
    list: ["Example", "Example 2"],
    // Print function prints the list
    print: function () {
     console.log(toDo.list);
    },
    // The add function should add a value to the list
    add: function () {
        console.log("What do you want to add to the ToDo List?");
        // Starts the prompt
        prompt.start();
        // Gets input called content
        prompt.get(['content'], function(err, result) {
            content = result.content
            // Pushed content to the list
            toDo.list.push(content);
        });
    }
}


// Main loop
function getCommand() {
    // Starts the prompt
    prompt.start();
    // Ask for name until user inputs "done"
    prompt.get(['timeManage'], function(err, result) {
        command = result.timeManage;
        // Checks if it is equal to exit; if so it exits the program
        if (command === 'exit') {
            console.log('Thanks for using timeManage.');
        } else {
            // Checks the remaining commands; if it finds one it executes
            switch (command){
                case "list":
                    toDo.print();
                    break;
                case "add":
                    toDo.add();
                    break;
            }
        // Loops the prompt unless the word exit is run
        getCommand();
        }
    });
}
getCommand();
```

Ps: I am a Node.js noob so if you spot any mistakes please tell me.

Thanks, Base

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var toDo = {
    // List that everything all ToDos will be stored within
    list: ["Example", "Example 2"],
    // Print function prints the list
    print: function () {
     console.log(toDo.list);
    },
    // The add function should add a value to the list
    add: function () {
        console.log("What do you want to add to the ToDo List?");
        // Starts the prompt
        prompt.start();
        // Gets input called content
        prompt.get(['content'], function(err, result) {
            content = result.content
            // Pushed content to the list
            toDo.list.push(content);
            getCommand();
        });
    }
}


function getCommand() {
    // Starts the prompt
    prompt.start();
    // Ask for name until user inputs "done"
    prompt.get(['timeManage'], function(err, result) {
        command = result.timeManage;
        // Checks if it is equal to exit; if so it exits the program
        if (command === 'exit') {
            console.log('Thanks for using timeManage.');
        } else {
            // Checks the remaining commands; if it finds one it executes
            switch (command){
                case "list":
                    toDo.print();
                    getCommand();
                    break;
                case "add":
                    toDo.add();
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I basically removed the `getCommand()` you were calling after the end of the switch case and called it in, one inside the switch case where `case "list"` and the other inside the function `toDo.add()`

I guess when you called getCommand() like before, both prompts for `content` and `timeManage` where executed on the console and that maybe the reason why you get double letter when you type a single letter.

Here is an image to demonstrate what happened with your code. I have consoled the text "Add" after `prompt.start()` in `toDo.add()` and "getCommand" after `prompt.start()` in `getCommand()`

[image]